# Validate FTP certificate by fingerprint or serialnumber

Tags: ftp, ssl, filezilla, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I want to establish a encrypted connection to an FTP server. FileZilla displays some information about the certificate sent from the server to me.

1. It would help me if there was a site that accepts fingerprint/serialnumber of certificate as its input and shows if there is a CA that confirms the domain of the certificate. Is there such a site/does anyone know such a site?

You find many sites to get information about SSL certificates online.

So I tried e.g. https://www.digicert.com/help/

2. But the fingerprint of the domain displayed on digicert.com and the fingerprint of the certificate (SHA1) displayed by FileZilla don't match.

Apparently as reading from the answer to the question [Buying SSL certificate for only one subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591114) there are CA's that support single certificates for different subdomains via SNAs. It seems to be the case (see [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/658109)) that one can sign a unlimited number of subdomains with the same certificate. However [thawte](https://www.thawte.de/ssl/san-uc-ssl-certificates/) only allows up to 25 different subdomains. So I guess there are different numbers of possible subdomains in a single certificate depending on the CA that signs the certificate?

3. So for different subdomains of the FTP server the certificates don't necessarily need to match do they?
4. The fingerprint is of the certificate is `22:ed:aa:c0:9f:0b:97:65:a2:20:b2:73:eb:52:5e:26:75:ee:b3:12`
5. As following the suggestion of [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591114) I facilitated WinSCP. But I get the message from WinSCP that it is a selfsigned certificate. So WinSCP definitely won't find it in the Windows trusted certificates, will it?

Answer (score 1):

1. I do not think it's possible to lookup domain name from a certificate fingerprint. I'm not aware of such registry.
2. The certificate used by an FTP server does not need to be the same as the one used for an HTTP server (which is shown by the https://www.digicert.com/help/).
3. Yes, each subdomain can have a different certificate.

If you show us, what fingerprint you get and the hostname, you may get a more concrete answer.

---

You can also try to use an FTP client that can verify the fingerprint against trusted Windows root certificates. So that you do not have to try verify it manually.

For example [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) does that (FileZilla does not).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*